# Are there colormap presets available in vtk?

Tags: python, vtk

My python script includes the line

```
lut = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
```

I would like to apply a preset. I have found [this link](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/vtkcolormaps-getpresetbyname-with-vtk-js-as-external-script/1183) discussing presets in the context of vtk-js but can find no equivalent in the vtkColorTransferFunction [class reference document](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkColorTransferFunction.html).

Is there anyway I can exploit presets? I have found transfer functions in paraview.simple module that permit presets. E.g.

```
  lut = paraview.simple.GetColorTransferFunction('dummy')                      
  lut.ApplyPreset('rainbow)
```

could I draw from the paraview presets by e.g. converting a PVLookuptable object to a vtk lookup table object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vtkColorSeries`. Basic use:

```py
colorSeries = vtk.vtkColorSeries()
colorSeries.SetColorScheme(vtk.vtkColorSeries.BREWER_DIVERGING_SPECTRAL_11)
lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
colorSeries.BuildLookupTable(lut, vtk.vtkColorSeries.ORDINAL)
```

Some (c++) doc here: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkColorSeries.html

Take a look at those examples:

*edit: update dead links*

- https://examples.vtk.org/site/Python/VisualizationAlgorithms/TensorEllipsoids/
- https://examples.vtk.org/site/Python/Visualization/CreateColorSeriesDemo/

Comment: Woah, `vtkColorSeries` has only very limited presets. Mmh. Maybe one can use `matplotlib`'s presets and use `numpy_to_vtk` into a `vtkLookupTable`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already in python you can use colormaps from matplotlib, like so:

```
# steal viridis from matplotlib
import vtk
from matplotlib.pyplot import get_cmap
cmap = get_cmap("viridis")
table = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
table.SetNumberOfTableValues(len(cmap.colors))
for i,val in enumerate(cmap.colors):
    table.SetTableValue(i,val[0],val[1],val[2])
```

Pick from here:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html